# Sql query - Select elements such that a condition is not met

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have this query in sqlite:

```
SELECT 
    'L_MEDIA_ARTIST'.'MEDIA_ID'
FROM \
    'L_MEDIA_ARTIST',
    'L_ARTIST_CAT',
    'ARTIST_CAT'
WHERE
    'L_ARTIST_CAT'.'ART_ID' == 'L_MEDIA_ARTIST'.'ART_ID'
AND
    'L_ARTIST_CAT'.'ART_CAT_ID' == 'ARTIST_CAT'.'ID'
AND
    ('ARTIST_CAT'.'NAME' == 'SINGER' OR 'ARTIST_CAT'.'NAME' == 'ACTOR')
```

which just selects all the media id such that the artist has at least one of the tag 'SINGER' or 'ACTOR'.

How can I change this query in order to obtain the list of all media such that the actor has neither the tag 'SINGER' nor the tag 'ACTOR'?

The involved tables are built up has follows:

```
CREATE TABLE 'L_MEDIA_ARTIST' (
'MEDIA_ID' INTEGER, 
'ART_ID' INTEGER, 
FOREIGN KEY('MEDIA_ID') REFERENCES MEDIA('ID'), 
FOREIGN KEY('ART_ID') REFERENCES ARTIST('ID'), 
UNIQUE('MEDIA_ID', 'ART_ID'));

CREATE TABLE 'L_ARTIST_CAT' (
'ART_ID' INTEGER,
'ART_CAT_ID' INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY('ART_ID') REFERENCES ARTIST('ID'),
FOREIGN KEY('ART_CAT_ID') REFERENCES ARTIST_CAT('ID'),
UNIQUE('ART_ID', 'ART_CAT_ID'));

CREATE TABLE 'ARTIST_CAT' (
'ID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
'NAME' TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation query for this, because you have to check that *none* of the values for a media are in the list.  Just looking on one row doesn't provide enough information:

```
SELECT l.MEDIA_ID
FROM L_MEDIA_ARTIST l JOIN
     L_ARTIST_CAT ac
     ON l.ART_ID = ac.ART_ID JOIN
     ARTIST_CAT c
     ON ac.ART_CAT_ID = c.ID
GROUP BY l.MEDIA_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.Name IN ('SINGER', 'ACTOR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Note that I also fixed the query:

- Introduced proper `join` syntax.  You should learn modern join syntax.
- Added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Removed the single quotes around table and column names, which just cause syntax errors.

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of times that "SINGER" and "ACTOR" are found in the data.  The `= 0` ensures there are none for a given media.

Answer (score 1):

The media IDs that you do *not* want can be retrieved with this query:

```
SELECT L_Media_Artist.Media_ID
FROM L_Media_Artist
JOIN L_Artist_Cat USING (Art_ID)
JOIN Artist_Cat ON L_Artist_Cat.Art_Cat_ID = Artist_Cat.ID
WHERE Artist_Cat.Name IN ('SINGER', 'ACTOR')
```

(This is the same as your first query.)

So you want all media that are not one of those:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Media
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT L_Media_Artist.Media_ID
                 FROM L_Media_Artist
                 JOIN L_Artist_Cat USING (Art_ID)
                 JOIN Artist_Cat ON L_Artist_Cat.Art_Cat_ID = Artist_Cat.ID
                 WHERE Artist_Cat.Name IN ('SINGER', 'ACTOR'))
```